Health insurance overturns original denial
Health insurance overturns original denial of prescription. However, member already paid out of pocket to receive medication in a timely manner. The price for the member is higher than contracted cost for the insurer.
What is the insurer's responsibility regarding this originally denied prescription? The $10 insurer contracted rate, or the $100 incurred by the member? How does the member receive the total cost incurred?

Based on the topic and question can we assume the United States?

The Explanation of Benefits (EOB) or some other official document showing the contract rate should be brought to the pharmacy and you should request a refund of the difference.
Either:

Insurance paid nothing to the pharmacy, you should have just paid $10

OR

Insurance paid $90 and you paid $10

Either way, the pharmacy has your money and you can request a refund from them.

The prescription was filled out-of-network as it was initially denied by insurer.

@paulj the answer doesn't change unless the insurance sent a check to you. The EOB should show their math and who got the money.
